# Detecting a click outside either of two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a little autocomplete dropdown which I want to hide when someone clicks outside the textbox. I've been using this so far

```
$("#input-group_ids").on("blur", function () {
    $(".input-dropdown").hide();
});
```

However my autocomplete dropdown has an overflow and a scroll bar if there are more than 10 options. When using the above code, clicking on the scroll bar closes the dropdown.

I need the dropdown to close only if the click is outside the textbox AND the dropdown itself. How do I do that?

Comment: Can u share the code in a fiddle

Comment: adding a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: I'll see if I can but there's a lot of other code to untangle from it

Comment: @roryok:Why do you need the above script.Wont you get this behaviour by default?[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/9yxwo72r/)

Comment: @SunilHari this is a custom plugin which doesn't use Jquery UI's autocomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet tested hope this will work

```
$("html").click (function () {
    $(".input-dropdown").hide();
});
$("#input-group_ids, .input-dropdown").click (function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation;
}
```

Comment: This answer is arguably the correct one, as while others "work" they're very inefficient.

Comment: this works! thanks. I also found another solution which is slightly different, I'll post that too

Comment: I admit this is a better one :)

Comment: its nice clear way of doing it,  I never thought of it but prefer  this approach

Comment: @roryok whats the other way will you able to share it

Comment: @Benjamin just shared it there. Also don't forget you need to include clicks on `$('.input-dropdown')` itself, not just `$("#input-group_ids")`.

Comment: @Benjamin, I'm ready to accept your answer if you just make that last edit - change the selector to `"#input-group_ids, .input-dropdown"`. otherwise the answer is a bit misleading

Comment: @roryok here i changed the selector

Answer (score 1):

In case you won't get clear with the `blur` event, try to register the click event to an element that is surrounding both the textbox and the dropdown. It may even be the `body`.

Then in the click event check the `event.target` element. If it is neither the textbox nor the dropdown, close it.

It feels clumsy, I know, but it is one of several working options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("*:not(#input-group_ids)").on("click", function () {
    $(".input-dropdown").hide();
});
```

Not tested because you didn't gave any jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)  the name explains it all and might work if you have a container on the dropdown and textbox

Answer (score 0):

a little hackish but might work.

```
$(elementContainingTheDropDownContent).on('mouseleave', function(e){
    $(window).on('click', function(e){
        //close dropdown
    })
}).on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(window).off('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer to this which is actually the best version I think

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$('#input-group_ids').is(e.target) && !$('.input-dropdown').is(e.target))
        $('.input-dropdown').hide();
});
```

This is slightly better than Benjamin's answer as it doesn't stop propagation of any clicks on  `$("#input-group_ids")`, which may have unintended consequences. However I'm accepting Ben's answer as it worked and solved my problem, and he deserves the credit. =)

EDIT: Actually my version is pretty similar to @singe31's version, so I upvoted that one too